# UITableViewCell gets new labels on scroll

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

Maybe this image will better explain the problem I have right now,

[image]

And this is the code I have right now.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

         let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell!

        let songAlbumImage = UIImageView()
        let songSongName = UILabel()

        songSongName.text = "\(indexPath.row + 1): \(self.songNames[indexPath.row])"
        songSongName.frame = CGRectMake(80, 0, screenWidth-80, 75)
        songSongName.font = UIFont(name: "ElliotSans-Regular", size: 18)
        songSongName.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        songSongName.numberOfLines = 2

        let url = NSURL(string: String(songAlbumCovers[indexPath.row]))
        let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)

        if (data != nil) {
            songAlbumImage.hnk_setImageFromURL(url!, placeholder: UIImage(named: "placeholder1.png"), format: Format<UIImage>(name: "image"), failure: { (error) -> () in }) { (image) -> () in
                songAlbumImage.image = image
            }
        } else {
            songAlbumImage.image = UIImage(named: "placeholder1.png")
        }

        songAlbumImage.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 75, 75)


        cell.addSubview(songAlbumImage)
        cell.addSubview(songSongName)

        return cell


    }
```

I just want the label to show up once

Comment: why you add songAlbumImage and songSongName in CellforrowIndex? that each time add new label and image thats why that appear duplicate. Use customCell for this

Comment: Cells are reused. You should create a UITableViewCell subclass and add the label & imageview to that.

Comment: there is a reason you have access to the interface builder, **use it**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use `UITableviewCell` instead of doing add `UIImageView` and `UILabel` in `CellForRowIndexPath` method. But as par your code try to add following two for loop for remove `UILabel` and `UIImageView` before add it subview to Cell:

**For UILabel:**

```
   for view in cell.subviews  {
        if let label = view as? UILabel {
            label.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
```

**For UIImageView:**

```
 for view in cell.subviews  {
        if let imgView = view as? UIImageView {
            imgView.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
```

Comment: you welcome but please don't use this technique for doing this task you must be learn custom-cell implementation. The use of Custom-Cell is the right way to doing this type of task with UITableView.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer :**
Add `cell.contentView.subviews.forEach({ $0.removeFromSuperview() })` right after `let cell = ...`

**Long answer :**
The cell is being "dequeued", it means that the cell is being reused as is.
So an old cell with an old text is being reused, and you need to empty it before adding your new views.

One more optimal solution would be to reuse the UILabel too, but you can remove them and recreate everything if you want. It will just be a less optimal solution.

Comment: Added comments on how dequeuing cell works and what does it mean. Also changed a little the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This it not an optimal soluion, but can you try to make the dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier nil?

Comment: When I try that, I get the error "Missing argument for parameter 'forIndexPath.row' in call

Comment: okay l only know Obj C so bare with me. First step make int rowVal = indexPath.row. Then make an NSString rowValString that is equal to rowVal but as a string (example @"1"). now use the rowValString as the reuse Indentifier. That way every cell will have its unique reuse identifier! Please update me when you do so